# Existence of Gibbs state on infinite graph

Tags: graph-theory, mathematical-physics, statistical-mechanics, gibbs-measure

Consider an infinite graph. In an [article](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1023/A:1021690414168) by Jonasson and Steif, the Ising model on this graph is defined as a generalization of the standard Ising model. On page 551, they cite a book by Georgii for the fact that there exists at least one Gibbs state. The book is called 'Gibbs measures and phase transitions' and can be downloaded by searching this title on Google followed by 'amu'. I checked page 71 where Jonasson and Steif referred to. However, at this page I found a theorem which contains a lot of unfamiliar terms.

The theorem does not contain the word graph, so I could not conclude to family of graphs the theorem applies.

Secondly, the word Ising model is not mentioned in the theorem and also it is not mentioned in chapter 4 which the theorem is in. The previous chapter contains a section about the one-dimensional Ising model; however, this is not the same as the Ising model on a general infinite graph.

Does the theorem on page 71 indeed state that the Ising model on an infinite graph has a Gibbs state? Does this really work for all graphs, also when they are not connected and/or uncountable?

Also, I am not sure whether this question belongs here or on Mathoverflow. Please let me know what you think.

Comment: This is a standard result. An accessible discussion (mostly on $\mathbb{Z}^d$, but the arguments apply to general graphs) can be found in Chapter 3 of [this book](https://www.unige.ch/math/folks/velenik/smbook/index.html), which is freely downloadable. It will be a much easier read than Georgii's book. Existence of infinite-volume states is discussed in Section 3.4. A much more general discussion (not restricted to the nearest-neighbor Ising model) can be found in Chapter 6 (the so-called DLR formalism, that is discussed in detail in Georgii's book).

Comment: Thank you for the comment! Do you think that the arguments apply to all graphs, or that there are certain extra conditions like connectedness?

Comment: Existence of at least one infinite-volume state does not require anything special (well, you need to be able to construct your infinite graph by a limiting procedure using a growing sequence of finite graphs, but that's extremely mild in practice). It is for the more complicated issue of uniqueness/non-uniqueness that additional properties become important.

Comment: You dont need connectedness for the limiting procedure?

Comment: No, connectedness is not required. The space of probability measures on $\{-1,1\}^V$ (where $V$ is the set of vertices of your graph) is sequentially compact. Therefore, if $(G_n)$ is a growing sequence of finite subgraphs converging to $G$, then you can always extract from the sequence of Ising measures $\mu_{G_n}$ on these graphs a converging subsequence. It is easy to show that the limiting measure is a Gibbs measure (this would be Theorem 6.26 in our book).

Comment: But it is probably more satisfactory to construct a limit explicitly. This can be done, for instance, by proving that the expectation $\langle\sigma_A\rangle_{G_n}$, where $\sigma_A=\prod_{i\in A}\sigma_i$ (for any finite $A\subset V$), is increasing in $n$. Since it is also bounded above (by $1$), it is converging. The monotonicity is a direct consequence of the GKS inequalities (see Section 3.6 of the book); this requires that the coupling constants are nonegative (i.e., the model is ferromagnetic) and the magnetic field is also nonnegative. The limiting state is called the free state.

Comment: One can prove a similar result (for general magnetic fields) for the so-called $+$ state, using the FKG inequality rather than GKS. (See Theorem 3.17 in the book, which is proved in Section 3.6.3.) Of course, these two states can in fact coincide. Determining when this is the case is a more complicated question (but well understood).

Comment: Thank you this helps a lot!